# java.lang.ClassFormatError: Invalid method Code length 75567 in class file

Tags: java, mockito, cobertura, powermockito

Greetings for the intelligent folks,

I am using cobertura along with **mockito** & **powermocktio** to get the code coverage.
I have **1.7** **java** version in my machine installed.

When I run the junit test cases in eclipse,all the test cases are getting passed.
But when I run ,

**mvn cobertura:cobertura**

I am getting following error.

> java.lang.ClassFormatError: Invalid method Code length 75567 in class
>   file

I researched and came to know that this is because of the memory size allocated for a metod by JVM.

My test class is  referring  a **legacy** class that has a static method which is very huge .**I cannot go and touch the legacy or main class for refractoring because of so many impacts .**

Any ideas to get rid of this exception without touching the main class would be appreciated.

Thanks
Pradeep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, exclude the legacy class from Cobertura instrumentation. Something like the following, when using Maven:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <instrumentation>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>aaa/**/Legacy.class</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </instrumentation>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Roger.Initially I thought excluding would not cover the coverage.But it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to disable bytecode verification (by adding -noverify to your JVM startup options) for your test environment.

Of course, that is not something you should do in your production environment; but given your requirements it might be the only chance you have to get your testing+coverage in place.

But then: be prepared for **more** ugly surprises. Powermock(ito) is "famous" for breaking coverage measurements. Actually, I think your chances to get such a setup to work reliably and to create robust coverage numbers is rather **small**.